# Fill a 2 dimensional array via index by closest range

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

It is a bit hard to describe what a i want so i start with and example:

```
Index   ArrayPos
1       0,0
2       1,0
3       0,1
4       1,1
5       2,0
6       2,1
7       2,2
8       0,2
9       1,2
10      1,2
11      3,0
12      3,1
```

and so on. Basically i want to fill the array not row by row or column by column but always the closest free place to 0,0 .

Would be great if duration of the algo would always be the same no matter wether if i want to get the array position for index 3 or 4237882348.

I tried some stuff with modulo but never got it.

Comment: Please reformat your example, it's even harder to understand without proper formatting.

Comment: thanks jswolf19 for formatting !

Comment: Why do you have 0,2 after 2,1 and 2,2 (and 3,1 before 0,3)? Why is 1,2 in twice?

Comment: I'm not able to understand what you need yet, I don't understand the sequence of ArrayPos

Comment: As per the question where to traverse is still confusing, close to 0,0 as in Row first or Column or Diagonally? If not the same logic as generating Gray Codes can be used I guess.

Comment: I find it hard to figure what "rule" you have in mind to generate the sequence. For instance, why should (1,0) come before (0,1), or (2,2) before (0,2)?

Comment: (1,0) and (0,1) have essentally the same distance so it doesnt matter which comes first. It should just be that 1 comes always first

Comment: The sequence is known as " Array associated with squares, by antidiagonals. " see http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C3%2C5%2C4%2C6%2C10%2C7%2C8%2C11&language=english&go=Search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the order of x, y and y, x, then this should work for you:

```
let x = ceiling(sqrt(Index)) - 1
let y = ceiling((Index - x^2)/2) - 1
if Index is odd, swap x and y
```

With this, though 4,4 comes before 5,0, so it depends on the order you want when getting into the larger numbers you don't have in your example...

Answer (score 2):

If algorithm can remember last position, it will be pretty easy.

You start with a **rank** number which is 0. For each rank r, there are `2r+1` positions free.
So `r`=0 => one position available which is 0,0,
For every rank you generate `2r+1` positions and store in an array. Values are generated by

for each `r`, loop and start creating positions `r,0 - 0,r - r,1 - 1,` r ... until `r,r`
So with every new index, use one of the positions created until no free position. Then increment the rank and carry on.

It was not clear which distance measurement is in mind but this works according to the example.

Comment: This would give `(4,4)` rank 4, before `(5,0)` rank 5. But `(5,0)` is closer to `(0,0)` with Euclidean distance measure.

Comment: You are right. I will remove mentioning Euclidian but it works according to the example provided.

Comment: The example does not make much sense, but I agree, this is probably what OP had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

If we take the p-norm where p=infinity (aka the maximum norm), which defines distance as the maximum co-ordinate, which looks like your example, then the following works in javascript (although the logic works in whatever language you please):

```
var i=1, L=0, n=15, x,y;
outer: while (true) {

  for (var j=1; j<=2*L+1; j++) {
    x = j<=L ? L : 2*L+1 - j;
    y = j<=L ? j-1 : L;
    document.write(x+" "+y+"<br/>");
    i++;
    if (i>n) {
      break outer;
    }
  }
  L++;
}
```

Note, that n is the number of elements you want to print, and you can change the `document.write` line to do whatever you want with it. So if you wanted to fill your 2d array with values from a single array:

`n = oneDimArray.length;`

And instead of document.write:

`newArray[x][y] = oneDimArray[i];`